# Cleaning/parsing a url wrapped by another site: Unfortunately Cleaner has stopped working

Tags: android, android-intent

Trying to create an app that will "clean" a url wrapped by facebook.com/l.php. code compiles fine, and I can even call it from the facebook app, but I get a black screen, and the new url i've parsed never seems to get handled.

Not new to Java, but new to droid..... :-o

anyways, manifest as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fusco.leetum.fblinkcleaner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="fusco.leetum.fblinkcleaner.Cleaner"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="facebook.com" /> 
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="m.facebook.com" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.facebook.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and the activity java ( finish() is there since it should do nothing if the user starts it, but since the parser code is in the onCreate() method, it needs to start every time):

```
    package fusco.leetum.fblinkcleaner;
```

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Cleaner extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_cleaner);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {

        final String baseurl = intent.getDataString();
        String newurl = baseurl;
        if (baseurl.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            String[] parseurl = baseurl.substring(baseurl.indexOf("?")+3).split("%2F");
            newurl = "http:/";
            for (int i=2; i < parseurl.length; i++) {
                newurl = "/"+parseurl[i];
            }
        }

        final Intent viewnewpage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newurl));
        startActivity(viewnewpage);

    }

    this.finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_cleaner, menu);
    return true;
}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! Instead of creating my own parser, I just had to use the Uri class stuff. What a learning curve. Android is a little different than normal desktop programming..... I guess you can't just bulldoze your way thru stuff. Oh well, manifest is the same, but here's the 'better' code. Prolly not the BEST, but still, hope this helps someone else :-D

This goes in the onCreate(...) method, replacing everything BUT the super call:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent(); // get intent that started activity

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) { // if called by view action
        Uri raw = intent.getData(); // get raw uri
        Uri cleanedUri = raw; // assign to allow 'pass thru' of not a wrapper
        String wrappedUri = raw.getQueryParameter("u"); // get the url defined in l.php?u=

        if (wrappedUri != null) { // if there was a u= parameter
            cleanedUri = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(wrappedUri)); // decode %stuff and parse to the proper uri
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, cleanedUri)); // broadcast new intent with new URI
    }

    this.finish(); // clear out and close this activity
```